# cURL Timeout On Cpanel

Tags: php, curl, cpanel, whm

I have a VPS server running WHM & Cpanel and I have been trying to find out where to set the cURL Timeout within the GUI. I have checked high and low and can't seem to find it. Anyone know where they hid that setting or if I need to ssh in and set it through the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just declare the timeout using

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURL_TIMEOUT, 1000);
```

In whatever script your using.

Alternative to CURL_TIMEOUT is CURL_CONNECTTIMEOUT

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: It appears that there is a setting that overrides it somewhere though.

Comment: Your web host in theory could be over riding your CURL timeouts, but the php config only enables/disables curl. Outside of that it should only be your setopt. Try a different host, or check your current hosts FAQ/support. documentation. The only other option would be PHPs default_socket_timeout variable in the ini. Maybe also try setting set_time_limit(0) at the start of the script?

Comment: I will look at the scripts, but since it's a VPS it has to be a setting on the server.